# force language in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a multilingual website (spanish and english) using Joomla 2.5.7. I want to `force` the default languague to spanish regardless of the default browser languague on the visitor's computer.

I already checked `Extensions -> Language Manager` and marke Spanish the default. But it keeps showing in english even after I clear the browser cache.

I also checked `Extensions -> Language Manager` Content tab and put `spanish` first without luck.

What I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was:
`Extensions -> Plug In Manager` then search for `System - Language Filter` and under `Basic Options` change `Language Selection for new Visitors` accordingly

Hope this helps someone else